# How to pass 'string' value from View to Controller by GET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to pass a 'string' value from View to Controller using **HttpGet** !!

I do the following, but it passes null:

*View.cshtml*

```
@Html.ActionLink("Profile", "Index", "UserInfo", new { name = User.Identity.Name }, new { hidefocus = "hidefocus" })
```

*UserInfoController.cs*

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(string user)
        {
            ...
        }
```

- *User.Identity.Name*
  is my string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it such as:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Profile", "Index", "UserInfo", new { name = User.Identity.Name }, null)
```

Comment: Thank you. What parametre is being nulled?

Comment: The value null is "object htmlAttributes", it not paramete. see : http://screencast.com/t/93xgOe894b5

Comment: also can I get rid of ?name in address bar?
I want it to be like 
`mysite.com/UserInfo/testuser` instead of `mysite.com/UserInfo?name=testuser/`

Comment: so u can use attributes of mvc 5: "[Route("UserInfo")]" for your ActionResult. Such as: http://screencast.com/t/xMduoP95Jo

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, just figured out, I forgot to set the type of parametre. Also, set one name for both of them, just in case.

*UserInfoController.cs*

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(string name) //check for area=""
        {
         ...
        }
```

*View.cshtml*

```
@Html.ActionLink("Profile", "Index", "UserInfo", new { name = (string)User.Identity.Name }, new { hidefocus = "hidefocus" })
```

Now it works properly.